# What are the loss function used in Gradient Boosting vs Random Forest? Would Gini/ Entropy work for both models?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, gini

When I look at Python package tutorials, I compared the function for GradientBoostingClassifier and RandomForestClassifier and found 2 differences:

1) GBM does not mention 'Gini' or 'Entropy', which is the impurity measure for node split used in Random Forest
2) Random Forest does not specify the loss function to minimize, while GBM has the parameter 'Loss'.

Based on my understanding, the split rule and loss function should be specified for both. Can anyone help answer this question?